# Implement MVVM With Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I created database in management studio, a model in my project with the ADO.NET Entity Data model for the tables.

I want to use the MVVM pattern to build forms and update, delete, insert data in my forms.

Can you please give me some guidance how to map the models with my viewmodels. Any tutorials would be nice, I`ve already spend whole day looking for something but got confused at the end.

Is there a simple project with Entity Framework and MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a contentious subject but I personally don't view change notification as belonging in the exclusive domain of the view/view-model relationship, so I add INPC to my models as as well and expose them in their corresponding view model. This can be done by either injecting proxies into your repositories at runtime (e.g. [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://jonas.follesoe.no/2009/12/23/automatic-inotifypropertychanged-using-dynamic-proxy/)) or by modifying the IL automatically at compile time (e.g. [Fody](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/using-fodypropertychanged-for-automatic.html)).

Answer (score 1):

From one noob to another - try searching for 'wpf mvvm entity framework example'. 
Here's what I found useful...
http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2010/09/10/MVVM-Tutorial-from-Start-to-Finish
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28209.wpf-entity-framework-mvvm-walk-through-1.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11644028)

Comment: A bit harsh! IMO the other comments from esteemed experts were way too technical for a noob..Don't you think StackOverflow has a broken link spider? Anyway I edited the post and got no constructive comment back.

Comment: Please don't take it as harsh, it's not intended I assure you.  It's just the default text for one of the review options - particularly when a post is primarily a link-only answer. It's not always easy to summarize the "*essential parts*" of a link into the answer, but it's good practice to try. In answer to your question - not that I know of. I've seen many broken links on SO - it's usually up to users to find and replace them with updated links else post comments stating the link is broken. BTW, I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use the repository pattern, to abstract your data access layer, so you viewmodels don't have a tight coupling to Entity Framework and remain easy to test.

Second, you can use an auto mapper like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map from your models to your ViewModels. However, you shouldn't use automappers to map from ViewModels to the View, so you'll have to manually create your model and pass it to your repository for insertion or updating.